# Make changes in mongodb only if all sub-queries execute successfully in Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to execute a function which consists of multiple sub-queries operating in multiple collections. They are then executed in Promise.all(). The problem is, that changes made by the first query are saved to the db even if the second or third query might fail (e.g. bonus is null). How could I prevent that from happening?

Some context: The purpose of this function is to track the transactions in which customers (who collect points in a loyalty program) cash in collected points to get the selected bonus in exchange.

```
export const addNewBonus = (req,res) => {
    let newBonus = new Bonus(req.body)

    //save new Bonus into database
    var f1 = newBonus.save()
    //increment timesChosen for the selected bonus of the involved shop
    var f2 = Shop.findOne({ "_id": req.body.shopId})
        .then((shop) => {
            const bonus = shop.bonuses.id(req.body.bonusId)
            if(bonus == null) throw "Bonus with specified bonusID not found for this shop";
            else bonus.timesChosen = bonus.timesChosen + 1
            return shop.save()
        })
    //update user's points
    var f3 = User.findOne({ "_id": req.body.userId})
    .then((user) => {
        const currentPointAmount = user.pAmount;
        if(currentPointAmount < req.body.bonusPrice) throw "Not enough Points on user account to choose this bonus"
        else{
            user.pAmount = user.pAmount - req.body.bonusPrice
        }
        return user.save()
    });

    Promise.all([f1, f2, f3])
    .then(results => {
        res.send(results)
    })
    .catch( err => {res.send(err)})
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a [multi-document transaction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions)

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look. :) Installing the required run-rs for local development with npm causes some problems on Windows however.